# Are the Uesugi siblings, Fūtarō and Raiha, named after the Japanese gods of wind and thunder, resp, Fūjin and Raijin?

Tags: japan, the-quintessential-quintuplets

Their names are [Fūtarō (Fuutarou)](https://5hanayome.fandom.com/wiki/Fuutarou_Uesugi) and [Raiha](https://5hanayome.fandom.com/wiki/Raiha_Uesugi). The gods are [Fūjin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F%C5%ABjin) and [Raijin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raijin). Is there some Japanese article that possibly talks about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this](https://dic.pixiv.net/a/%E4%B8%8A%E6%9D%89%E3%82%89%E3%81%84%E3%81%AF), your guess seems to be correct.

> 名前の由来は風神雷神の雷神で、風太郎と対になっている。
>
> (The origin of the name is Raijin from Fujin&Raijin, pairing with Futaro.)

Comment: Same with their dad? https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/66807/is-the-dad-isanari-of-the-uesugi-siblings-f%c5%abtar%c5%8d-and-raiha-named-after-izanami