# Is the dad Isanari of the Uesugi siblings, Fūtarō and Raiha, named after Izanami or Izanagi given the kids are named after Fūjin and Raijin?

Tags: the-quintessential-quintuplets

The kids' names are [Fūtarō (Fuutarou)](https://5hanayome.fandom.com/wiki/Fuutarou_Uesugi) and [Raiha](https://5hanayome.fandom.com/wiki/Raiha_Uesugi).

As we see [here](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/66730/are-the-uesugi-siblings-f%C5%ABtar%C5%8D-and-raiha-named-after-the-japanese-gods-of-wind) referencing [this](https://dic.pixiv.net/a/%E4%B8%8A%E6%9D%89%E3%82%89%E3%81%84%E3%81%AF), they are named after the gods, resp, [Fūjin (Fuujin)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F%C5%ABjin) and [Raijin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raijin).

I notice the gods have Izanami as a parent, and then Izanami apparently has a child with another god, Izanagi. So [Isanari](https://5hanayome.fandom.com/wiki/Isanari_Uesugi) is named after Izanami or Izanagi, right?

Comment: It is an interesting guess, but I can't find any website mentioning this (You could be the first one). One thing is that 勇也 is much more commonly read Yuuya, but [Isanari](https://b-name.jp/%E8%B5%A4%E3%81%A1%E3%82%83%E3%82%93%E5%90%8D%E5%89%8D%E8%BE%9E%E5%85%B8/m/yomi/%E3%81%84%E3%81%95%E3%81%AA%E3%82%8A/610977) seems an authentic one (not just made up). That said, it is possible the author chose it because of the similarity to Izanagi.

Comment: @sundowner a posteriori: Devil's proof. A priori: post as answer anyway man/girl? XD thanks as usual! (i don't have to accept it. so community will bump it and then by cunningham's law we can see if we're wrong. idk how we'd know if we'd be right without an article or word from the author though.)